# 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade goes wrong and freezes

Tags: upgrade

After trying to upgrade to 16.04 my system froze halfway to installing. I have re-installed 14.04 alongside 16.04 as it is. Logging into 16.04 only puts me at the command prompt. I want to recover my emails and contacts etc. and copy to another partition or USB flash drive. However, although I can find my files I cannot access any other partition or the USB drive. Can somebody tell me how to identify these other areas so I can copy there.
Thanking you for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you run the command "sudo blkid"?

Comment: Many thanks Sahib. I have recovered my emails and address box and re-installed my Thunderbird profile.

Comment: no problem! it's my duty to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: This method is a *tad* convulted, but hey, no GUI = command-line fu :)

---

### Step 1: Locate the partitions where you want to copy

Run the command `sudo blkid`, you should get output similar to this:

```
...
/dev/sda1: UUID="gibberish" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="more gibberish"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MYUSB" UUID="NUMBERS" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="gibberish"
...
```

If you want to transfer to a USB, look for partitions with the `vfat` file system and a label containing the word "**USB**".

Once you have located the partitions you want to copy to, continue.

### Step 2: Mount the partition(s)

You can mount the partitions like so:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt (if it doesn't exist)
sudo mkdir /mnt/usb
sudo mkdir /mnt/hdd
sudo mount [usb partition here] /mnt/usb
sudo mount [hdd partition here] /mnt/hdd
```

### Step 3: Copy files

Let's say you wanted to copy over `/home/bob/folder`.

If you don't care about permissions and file ownership, you can use `cp` with the `--recursive` flag:

```
cp --recursive /home/bob/folder /mnt/usb/folder
cp --recursive /home/bob/folder /mnt/hdd/folder
```

If you **do** care about permissions and owners, use the `rsync` command:

```
rsync -ar /home/bob/folder /mnt/usb/folder
rsync -ar /home/bob/folder /mnt/hdd/folder
```

### Step 4: Unmount the partitions

Once you're done with them, unmount them:

```
sudo umount /mnt/hdd
sudo umount /mnt/usb
```

### Step 5: Complete!

You've backed up your stuff!